# ¿Cómo guardar una gráfica generada con SymPy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

Uso `sympy.plotting.plot` para graficar una función lo cual consigo sin problemas, el problema es que quiero guardar una imagen en disco del gráfico y no se como hacerlo.

Este es mi código:

```
import os
os.system('cls')
from sympy import *

t,w=symbols('t w')
n,m,k,l=symbols('n m k l', int=True)
p,j=symbols('p j', float=True)
f,g=symbols('f F',cls=Function)
f=input("f(t)=")

f=sympify(f)
p=input("Periodo T=")
p=sympify(p)
w0=2*pi/p
print("w0=2",w0)

#calculamos los coeficientes de la serie de Fourier trigonométrica
a0=(1/p)*integrate(f,(t,-p/2,p/2))
print("a0=",a0)
an=(2/p)*integrate(f*cos(n*w0*t),(t,-p/2,p/2))
print("an=",an)
bn=(2/p)*integrate(f*sin(n*w0*t),(t,-p/2,p/2))
print("bn=",bn)

#aproximamos la serie de Fourier 
m=input("Armonicos deseados:")
m=sympify(m)
print("f(t)=")
s=a0
for i in range(1,m+1):
    s=s+(an*cos(n*w0*t)).subs(n, i)
for k in range(1,m+1):
    s=s+(bn*sin(n*w0*t)).subs(n, k)

#graficamos
plotting.plot(s,ylim=(-8,8),xlim=(-8,8))
```

Comment: Hola @ArturoDelgado, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Arturo bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿A qué te refieres con "imágenes de una ecuación SymPy"? ¿guardar una imagen de  la gráfica final? Edita la pregunta e intenta explicar mejor que quieres conseguir, tal y como está la pregunta no es muy clara. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias FJSevilla, tomaré tu consejo, y pues si, lo que quiero es guardar la imagen de la gráfica final. Saludos y gracias por tu tiempo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sympy.plotting.plot`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html#sympy.plotting.plot.Plot) tiene un método `save` que te permite guardar una imagen de la gráfica pasando como único argumento la ruta.

Solo necesitas una variable que haga referencia a la instancia y luego usar su método `save`:

```
#graficamos
graf = plotting.plot(s,ylim=(-8,8),xlim=(-8,8))
graf.save("graf.png")
```

El resultado puede diferir en función del backend (p.e Matplotlib) que se esté usando.

Comment: OOOOHHHHH muchisimas gracias!!! Eres un genio FJSevilla, funciona perfecto!

Comment: Disculpa, ¿cómo puedo hacer para que "n" tome estrictamente valores enteros mayores o iguales a cero?